# How to dynamically create JS Map() based on data

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am splitting each array into a Map(), currently it is 16 base colors (black, blue, brown, etc) and their arrays contain common / alias names for those colors.

How do I dynamically create Map Objects based on the base color name instead of predefining each map variable in advance?

```js
const colorMap = {
"black": {
    "filterHelper": [
        "Black",
        "Black Agate",
        "Black Caiman",
        "Black Cherry",
        "Black Croco",
        "Black Gato",
        "Black Oil",
        "Black Onyx",
        "Black Patent",
        "Black Patent Croco",
        "Black Pearl-Chocolate Pearl",
        "Black Shimmer",
        "Black Shimmer C",
        "Black Shimmer D",
        "Black Shimmer R",
        "Black Shimmer S",
        "Black Shine",
        "Black Sparkle",
        "Black Zebra",
        "Black-Acorn",
        "..Black-Anthracite",
        "Black-Bali Blue"
      ]
   },
  "blue": {
    "filterHelper": [
        "Blue",
        "Other blue synonyms.."
      ]
   },
    "brown": {
    "filterHelper": [
        "Brown",
        "Other brown synonyms.."
      ]
   },
   
}




let blackMap = new Map();
    blueMap = new Map();
    brownMap = new Map();

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(colorMap)) {

  let values = Object.values(value)

  let colorName = values[0][0];
  let colorArray = value[0];

  if(colorName == "Black") {
    console.log('Black');
    blackMap.set(colorName, colorArray);
  }
  if(colorName == "Blue") {
    console.log('Blue');
    blueMap.set(colorName, colorArray);
  }
  if(colorName == "Brown") {
    console.log('Brown');
    brownMap.set(colorName, colorArray);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hard to understand... There's no such thing as `"brown"` in your sample data, there's only a suffixed `"blue"` -  why don't you clarify and make obvious the problem? Also this reminds me of: [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) You say you have two large datasets - where are they in your example code? I see one dataset.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The other data set is outside of the scope of this question, my apologies. Array is corrected, original is over character limit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use object destructuring if you are trying to access these dynamically created variables later on:

```js
const colorMap = {
  black: {
    filterHelper: [
      "Black",
      "Black Agate",
      "Black Caiman",
      "Black Cherry",
      "Black Croco",
      "Black Gato",
      "Black Oil",
      "Black Onyx",
      "Black Patent",
      "Black Patent Croco",
      "Black Pearl-Chocolate Pearl",
      "Black Shimmer",
      "Black Shimmer C",
      "Black Shimmer D",
      "Black Shimmer R",
      "Black Shimmer S",
      "Black Shine",
      "Black Sparkle",
      "Black Zebra",
      "Black-Acorn",
      "Black-Anthracite",
      "Black-Bali Blue",
    ],
  },
};
let dynamicColorMaps = {};

for (let key in colorMap) {
  let mapKey = `${key}Map`;
  dynamicColorMaps[mapKey] = new Map().set(key, colorMap[key].filterHelper); 
}

let { blackMap } = dynamicColorMaps;

console.log(blackMap)
```

However, I'm not sure if this solution is the best for the problem you are trying to solve. You may want to provide more information regarding your inputs and outputs.

Comment: Your demo returns currently an empty Object `{}` Was this intended?

Comment: Not sure why it does this... it works correctly in devtools, however.

Comment: Yes, indeed, It's the Stack Overflow Snippets "terminal" that cannot dynamically expand live Objects. True.

Comment: Interesting! Good to know for future snippets.

Comment: @daxicks shouldn't this return true?  console.log(dynamicColorMaps.blackMap.has('Black Agate'))

Comment: This is where it can get confusing. dynamicColorMaps is an object that contains a list of maps. Each map has a single key -- "black" for example -- that is set to an array of colors. As such, the operation you would have to do using this data structure is: `blackMap.get("black").includes("Black Agate")`. To use the .has operator, you would want to set your dynamic keys to a Set (e.g. `dynamicColorMaps["blackMap"] = new Set(colorMap[key].filterHelper)`)